Accentuating the appearance of convergence of the Möbius function Dirichlet series on the line $\sigma = \frac{2}{3}$ in the critical strip
Set the constant $c$ to:
$$c = -\frac{3}{4}$$
which is in the interval: $$-1 < c < 0$$
and let the matrix $A$ be:
$$A(n,k)=[k|n] - [n=k](1+c)$$
Then form the matrix power series:
$$M=\sum _{n \geq 0}^{\text{N}} (-1)^{n} A^{n}$$
where $N \rightarrow \infty$ but in the program is set to some large number like $N=150$.
The first column $\mu_{c}(n)$ in the matrix $M$ is then the Möbius function $\mu(n)$ plus some kind of binomial sum of powers of $c$ that appears to involve OEIS sequence A354349.
Then plot the Dirichlet series with this modified Möbius function $\mu_{c}(n)$ in gray:
$$\Re\left(c+ 1 \Bigg/ \sum _{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mu_{c}(n)}{n^{\sigma+i t}}\right) \tag{1}$$
together with the Riemann zeta function: $$\Re(\zeta (\sigma + i t))\tag{2}$$ in blue on the line: $$\sigma = \frac{2}{3}$$


Why are $(1)$ and $(2)$ so close to each other?

Mathematica 14:
nn = 150; (*increase nn for better precision*)
c = -3/4;  (*constant to vary in the range:-1<c<0*)
A = Table[Table[If[Mod[n, k] == 0, 1, 0], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}] - 
   IdentityMatrix[nn]*(1 + c);
moebiusC = 
  N[ParallelSum[(-1)^(n + 0)*MatrixPower[A, n], {n, 0, nn}]][[All, 1]];
sigma = 2/3;
Plot[Re[(1/Sum[moebiusC[[n]]/n^(N[sigma] + I*t), {n, 1, nn}] + 
     c)], {t, 0, 60}, PlotStyle -> Gray];
Plot[Re[Zeta[N[sigma] + I*t]], {t, 0, 60}];
Show[%, %%]

Compare it to the usual Möbius function Dirichlet sum in gray:
$$\Re\left(1 \Bigg/ \sum _{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{\sigma+i t}}\right) \tag{3}$$
and:
$$\Re(\zeta (\sigma + i t)) \tag{2}$$
in blue for the same sigma:
$$\sigma = \frac{2}{3}$$

nn = 150; 
sigma = 2/3;
Plot[Re[(1/Sum[MoebiusMu[n]/n^(N[sigma] + I*t), {n, 1, nn}])], {t, 0, 
   60}, PlotStyle -> Gray];
Plot[Re[Zeta[N[sigma] + I*t]], {t, 0, 60}];
Show[%, %%]

$\mu_{c}(n)$ for $N=5$ is:
$$\mu_{c}(1)=c^5+c^4+c^3+c^2+c+1$$
$$\mu_{c}(2)=-5 c^4-4 c^3-3 c^2-2 c-1$$
$$\mu_{c}(3)=-5 c^4-4 c^3-3 c^2-2 c-1$$
$$\mu_{c}(4)=-5 c^4+6 c^3+3 c^2+c+0$$
$$\mu_{c}(5)=-5 c^4-4 c^3-3 c^2-2 c-1$$
I am not sure, but the coefficients of $\mu_{c}(n)$ for $n>1$ appear to be approximately:
$$\mu_{c}(n)=\underbrace{ \underset{a = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2}} \mu(a)c^{0} + \underset{ab = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2} \sum_{b \geq 2}} \mu(a)\mu(b)c^{1} + \underset{abc = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2} \sum_{b \geq 2} \sum_{c \geq 2}} \mu(a)\mu(b)\mu(c)c^{2} + \underset{abcd = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2} \sum_{b \geq 2} \sum_{c \geq 2} \sum_{d \geq 2}} \mu(a)\mu(b)\mu(c)\mu(d)c^{3} + \cdots -Nc^{(N-1)}}_{\text{#alternating sums}>\frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}}$$
where: $$\mu(n) =  \underbrace{\underset{1 = n} 1 - \underset{a = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2}} 1 + \underset{ab = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2} \sum_{b \geq 2}} 1 - \underset{abc = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2} \sum_{b \geq 2} \sum_{c \geq 2}} 1 + \underset{abcd = n}{\sum_{a \geq 2} \sum_{b \geq 2} \sum_{c \geq 2} \sum_{d \geq 2}} 1 - \cdots}_{\text{#alternating sums}>\frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}}$$
from the comment in: https://oeis.org/A007428
"a(n) = Sum_{abc=n} mu(a)*mu(b)*mu(c). - Benedict W. J. Irwin, Mar 02 2022"

Previously posted at mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/476345/25104

From Wikipedia:
The statement that the equation:
$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$
is valid for every $s$ with real part greater than 1/2, with the sum on the right hand side converging, is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis.
